# how to parse json array using Litjson?

Tags: c#, json, arrays, litjson

I am developing an application in which i am using data came from server in the json format.
However i am able to parse normal json data but failed to parse the json data with arrays,

the json response is given below,

```
[{"id_user":"80","services":
    [{"idservice":"3","title":"dni-e","message":"Texto para el dni-e"},
     {"idservice":"4","title":"Tarjeta azul","message":"Texto para la tarjeta azul"}]
}]
```

how can i read this json array?

**Note**:I am using Litjson for parsing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create yourselft following POCO objects:

```
public class Service
{
    public int idservice { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }

    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class UserServices
{
    public int id_user { get; set; }

    public List<Service> services { get; set; }
}
```

LitJSON will deserialize this out-of-the-box:

```
UserServices services = JsonMapper.ToObject<UserServices>(rawJson);
```

As an alternative you can use non-generic variant (below sample would wrote all data to the console):

```
JsonData data = JsonMapper.ToObject(rawJson);
Console.WriteLine("User id: {0}", data["id_user"]);
Console.WriteLine("Services:");
for (int i = 0; i < data["services"].length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("    Id: {0}; Title: {1}; Message {2}", data["services"][i]["idservice"], data["services"][i]["title"], data["services"][i]["message"]);
}
```