# How to take a particular field from json data in unity

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, litjson

- Using google reverse geocoding i get a json.
- i need to access a particular field from it.

i tried the following code

```
private void Processjson(string jsonString)
{
    JsonData jsonvale = JsonMapper.ToObject(jsonString);

    Debug.Log (jsonvale["status"].ToJson()); // which prints "ok" on console


    parseJSON parsejson;

    string name = jsonvale["results"]["formatted_address"].ToString();
     debug.log(name);
}
```

here i cant print the name (formatted_address)

my json file is as below

```
    {
   "results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Udumalpet-Poosaripatti-Negamam Road",
           "short_name" : "Udumalpet-Poosaripatti-Negamam Road",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Seelakkampatti",
           "short_name" : "Seelakkampatti",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
           "short_name" : "TN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "642205",
           "short_name" : "642205",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Udumalpet-Poosaripatti-Negamam Road, Seelakkampatti, Tamil Nadu 642205, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 10.6607381,
              "lng" : 77.1360873
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 10.6576768,
              "lng" : 77.1228984
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 10.6581087,
           "lng" : 77.13010969999999
        },
        "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 10.6607381,
              "lng" : 77.1360873
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 10.6576768,
              "lng" : 77.1228984
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJ6SNTGUk0qDsRJs-tBBDJ6Ag",
     "types" : [ "route" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "642205",
           "short_name" : "642205",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
           "short_name" : "TN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Tamil Nadu 642205, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 10.698639,
              "lng" : 77.26073269999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 10.6228222,
              "lng" : 77.05489420000001
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 10.6583181,
           "lng" : 77.1830243
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 10.698639,
              "lng" : 77.26073269999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 10.6228222,
              "lng" : 77.05489420000001
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJ9en3D_s0qDsRIcoj9NdDJRg",
     "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "short_name" : "Coimbatore",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
           "short_name" : "TN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 11.4057969,
              "lng" : 77.1766741
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 10.21881,
              "lng" : 76.656036
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 10.9675289,
           "lng" : 76.91820969999999
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 11.4057969,
              "lng" : 77.1766741
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 10.21881,
              "lng" : 76.656036
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJtRyXL69ZqDsRl3v5ZMPoVUA",
     "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
           "short_name" : "TN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Tamil Nadu, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 13.496666,
              "lng" : 80.3464511
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 8.0690069,
              "lng" : 76.23055409999999
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 11.1271225,
           "lng" : 78.6568942
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 13.496666,
              "lng" : 80.3464511
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 8.0774075,
              "lng" : 76.23055409999999
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJM5YYsYLFADsR8GEzRsx1lFU",
     "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 35.5087008,
              "lng" : 97.39535869999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 6.4626999,
              "lng" : 68.1097
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 20.593684,
           "lng" : 78.96288
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 35.5087008,
              "lng" : 97.39498069999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 6.7535159,
              "lng" : 68.16288519999999
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc",
     "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
  }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

the error when i log the name is as follows

```
InvalidOperationException: Instance of JsonData is not a dictionary
LitJson.JsonData.EnsureDictionary ()
```

How can i log the field [formatted_address]

Comment: debug.log("name") is going to print text name - if you want to print contents of variable you have to use it without quotes: debug.log(name);

Comment: sorry i actually mean name

Comment: @Rafal Ziolkowski i have edited the question

Comment: Looks like results contains array, you should try jsonvale["results"][0]["formatted_address"]

Comment: Ok, I don't know this json library but check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469666/how-to-parse-json-array-using-litjson

Comment: thanks man it works.. why we used [0] ?, can u please tell

Comment: It's an array. Json format encloses arrays in []) so in this case you want to fetch 1st element of 0-based array and this is notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is Unity, we already have JsonUtility which is built-in. I just copied your json string and generated below class from [JsonUtils](http://www.jsonutils.com/)

```
public class AddressComponent
{
    public string long_name;
    public string short_name;
    public List<string> types;
}

public class Northeast
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

public class Southwest
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

public class Bounds
{
    public Northeast northeast;
    public Southwest southwest;
}

public class Location
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

public class Viewport
{
    public  northeast;
    public  southwest;
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Bounds bounds;
    public Location location;
    public string location_type;
    public Viewport viewport;
}

public class Result
{
    public List<AddressComponent> address_components;
    public string formatted_address;
    public Geometry geometry;
    public string place_id;
    public List<string> types;
}

public class Example
{
    public List<Result> results;
    public string status;
}
```

Add above classes in single script and add it into the unity.
Now try this code to get the formatted addresses.

```
private void Processjson(string jsonString)
{
    Example example = JsonUtility.FromJson<Example>(jsonString);

    Debug.Log (example.results[0].formatted_address);
}
```

You can rename the **Example** class if you want

Comment: Edited to replace properties with fields and IList with List since Unity doesn't serialize those.

Comment: can you share ur mail id.. will delete the comment once i get it