# Parsing through my array in the JSON object (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine

I currently have a JSON file with the following data:

```
   {
   "user":"me",
   "payment_method":"card",
   "items_bought":[
      {
         "id":"001",
         "name":"desk",
         "delivered":"false"
      },
      {
         "id":"455",
         "name":"chair",
         "delivered":"false"
      },
      {
         "id":"234",
         "name":"mouse pad",
         "delivered":"false"
      },
      {
         "id":"135",
         "name":"cabinet",
         "delivered":"false"
      }
   ]
}
```

I wanna parse through the "items_bought" so i could get the name of each item in the array.

I am currently using this code to read my JSON file. I just need help for the loop so i could get the member or the array.

```
jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/account_response.json");
jsonMessage = JsonMapper.ToObject(jsonString);
Debug.Log(jsonMessage["user"].ToString()); //prints value of user
Debug.Log(jsonMessage["payment_method"].ToString()); //prints value of payment_method
```

Any heads up would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your json is not [valid](http://json2csharp.com/). When you fix it, see duplicate for how to de-serialize json array

Comment: you may also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469666/how-to-parse-json-array-using-litjson

Comment: @rudolf_franek thanks! that solved my problem. i was hoping i could find a solution that doesnt involve de-serializing